# How to Iterate through nested Map<Integer, List<abc>>

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

How to Iterate through nested `Map<Integer, List<abc>>`

```
Class Abc {
    int id ;
    String name;
    Date startDate;
    int rowNum;
}

List<Abc> dupList = list
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(v-> v.size()>=2)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, List<Abc>> byRows = dupList
                                 .stream()
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum));

Map contains fallowing data
Key             value(abc List)
rowNum: 1       rowNum: 1
                startDate: 01/01/2019
                endDate:12/31/2099
                name: Test1
                Id:101
rowNum: 1       rowNum: 1
                startDate: 01/01/2020
                endDate:12/31/2099
                name: Test1
                Id:111
rowNum: 3       rowNum: 3
                startDate: 01/01/2020
                endDate:12/31/2099
                name: Test4
                Id:342
rowNum: 3       rowNum: 3
                startDate: 01/01/2020
                endDate:12/31/2099
                name: Test4
                Id:348
```

Now I want to print values for key and corresponding List of class Abc.

When I am trying to print the map

```
Map<Integer, List<Abc>> collect = byRows
                                   .entrySet()
                                   .stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                                        Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(collect);
```

I am getting output as `{1=[Abc@1d72673f, Abc@1cffb7e0], 3=[Abc@522530e9, Abc@58dc69f2]}`
I am not getting actual values from nested loop from ArrayList of class Abc.

expected output:

```
I want to print startDate for each all rows 
Ex: rowNum  startDate 
    1       01/01/2019 {startDate}
            01/01/2020

    3       startDate: 01/01/2020
            startDate: 01/01/2020
```

Comment: what output you are expecting? and also override the `toString()` method of `Abc` class you will be the expected output

Comment: "not getting actual values from nested loop from ArrayList of class Abc." What do you mean by this? What is `Term`? Do you maybe just need a `toString()` method?

Comment: I update the expected result. I want to print startDate in List of class Abc to corresponding rowNum(Key) from Map. Also Term is class name Abc.. I forgot to change i modified now.

Comment: check my answer it will print the output that you need, but still you have to format it @user5982569

Comment: It worked and I will format the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are grouping by `rowNum` and filtering if list has 2 elements. so you can do this all in one step. No need to group by twice

```
Map<Integer, List<Term>> collect = list
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(v-> v.getValue().size()>=2)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Then if you want to print each element from `Map` then use `forEach`, still you might need formatting the data based on your requirement

```
collect.forEach((k,v)-> {
             System.out.println("RowNum is :"+k);
             v.forEach(o->System.out.println(o.getStartDate()));
           });
```

Comment: collect.forEach((k,v)-> {
            System.out.println("RowNum is :"+k);        
            for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {
             System.out.println(v.get(i).getBnftId());
            }
          });  with reference of above code I am now able to manipulate data in values of the map list.

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the toString() method of Abc.when you call the "System.out.println" ,it will call toString() method and return results.